# Changing Vertical Menu to Horizontal Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am fairly new CSS and I have been tasked with changing the menu in the website to a more accessible horizontal menu on each page. I am using WordPress with the Intergalactic Theme. The dashboard allows me to make custom CSS additions.

[Custom CSS editor in WordPress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApkSt.jpg)

How can I change this?

Here is the code:

view-source:https://sites.wp.odu.edu/thelambertgroup/biography/

Comment: Please provide more context as to what you are trying to do and what you already tried.  When you say "accessible", are you talking about WCAG?

Answer (score 0):

I need your code please.

You probably need to set your each `menu button` with `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to align them horizontally.

Comment: "view-source:https://sites.wp.odu.edu/thelambertgroup/biography/"